# how to Prove $τ=\inf\{t:B(t)=\max\limits_{0<s<1}B(s)\}$ is a random variable?where B(t) is brownian motion process

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-calculus, stopping-times

How to prove $τ=\inf\{t:B(t)=\max\limits_{0<s<1}B(s)\}$ is a random variable？

$B(t)$ is brownian motion process

only random variable is needed，don‘t have to prove it not stopping time.

i tried to rewrite τ as
inf{t:B(t)-M(t)=0}，
where M（t）=max B(s) , 0< s< 1，
there is a collateray noting that
 B(t)-M(t)===|B(t)|===M（t） in distribution.
then τ=inf{t:M(t)=0}，i can only reach here.

Comment: A few details that might become relevant: 1. where does $t$ belong to? The interval $[0,1]$ as well? 2. Why do you take a maximum over an open set? It might be a supremum and not a maximum. However by continuity of brownian motion, it's equivalent to taking the maximum over $[0,1]$.

Comment: In order to show that $\tau$ is a random variable, you could start from the very definition. For example, if you show that the sets $\{\tau \leq T\}$ are measurable for all $T\in \mathbb{R}$, then it will be a random variable

Comment: how to show τ<=T are measurable？

Comment: Try with definitions. For example, $\tau\leq T$ if and only if $B(t)\leq \max_{[0,T]} B(s)$ for all $t\geq T$. Try to write this in terms of equality of two sets, express the second as an intersection of sets, then use continuity of brownian motion to reduce it to a countable intersection.

Comment: Dumb question: is this perhaps similar to proving how $\min_{n} \{n | X_n = \max_{m} X_m \}$ is a random variable? That is, it doesn't matter that $B_t$ is Brownian?

Comment: then what is the defination of {X}？perhaps brownian motion is a special case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Y(t)=\sup \{B(u):0 \leq u\leq t\}$. Let us show that $\tau \leq t$ if and only of $Y(t)=Y(1)$. If $Y(t)=Y(1)$ then (since continuous functions attain their maximum on any compact set) there exists $s \in [0,t]$ such that $B(s)=Y(t)=Y(1)$ and hence $B(s)=\sup \{B(u):0 \leq u\leq 1\}$ which implies $\tau \leq s$ by definition of $\tau$. Hence $\tau \leq t$. Conversely, suppose $\tau \leq t$. Suppose, if possible, $Y(t) \neq Y(1)$. Since $Y(t) \leq Y(1)$ we get $Y(t)=\sup \{B(u):0 \leq u\leq t\} <Y(1)$. By continuity of Brownian paths this implies $Y(t+\epsilon)<Y(1)$for some $\epsilon >0$. This implies that the set $\{v\in [0,1]: Y(v)=Y(1)\}$ contains no point of the interval $[0,t+\epsilon]$ so the infimum of this set is $\geq t+\epsilon $. By definition of $\tau$ this means $\tau \geq t+\epsilon$ which is a contradiction. We have proved the claim that $\tau \leq t$ if and only of $Y(t)=Y(1)$. It remains to show that $\{Y(t)=Y(1)\}$ is measurable. For this it is enough to show that $Y(t)$ is a measurable function for each $t$. But $Y(t)=\sup \{B(\frac i {2^{n}}):0\leq i\leq 2^{n} t,n \geq 1\}$ which is meaurable.